# How can I overwrite a file through Dockerfile in docker container?

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile

I have to overwrite a file through Dockerfile. In particular on an Ubuntu container with Apache and PHP and I have to overwrite the file php5-cgi.conf.
I tried to use the following command:

```
COPY php5-cgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5-cgi.conf
```

but I had the error: `File already exists`

I have also tried to use the following command

`RUN cp -f php5-cgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

but the file is not copied when the container is running, Is there any advice on this?

Comment: You should choose an accepted answer.

Comment: As it's a year later and you still haven't done it: Please choose an answer.

Comment: This is the only thing they've ever done on this site. They're probably never coming back.

Answer (score 74):

Drop the file name from the destination:

```
COPY php5-cgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
```

The destination is an ***absolute path*** (not filename), or a path relative to the work directory, into which the source will be copied inside the destination container.

Comment: I’d rather like to scare-quote the “into which.”

Answer (score 18):

I just tested following docker file with no problem.

```
from debian:jessie
COPY debian_version /etc/debian_version
```

As PolarisUser stated in comments, you need to put `debian_version` in the same folder as `dockerfile` or use `absolute path`.
Another way would be mounting the file when running the container.

```
docker run -d -v php5-cgi.conf:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5-cgi.conf --name your_container_name <imagename:tag> <startup command>
```

Comment: Just make sure to have debian_version in the same location that the Dockerfile is. This is the correct answer though.

Answer (score 9):

```
docker cp "yourfilename" "containername":/destination
```

Below is a working example:

```
docker cp config.json bigdataapp:/app/src/bigdatapp/wwwroot/assets/config/config.json
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but not for this question;